# No option "Postgres " as database type on GRAFANA

Tags: database, postgresql, grafana

I installed grafana as explained on the website. http://docs.grafana.org/installation/debian/ And since I'm using postgresql as database I wanted tp add may data source. Unfortunately I didn't found the option postgres (only Graphit, MySQL, InfluxDB and two other types were there). There is even any postgres plugin on the website (The one that I found didn't work https://github.com/sraoss/grafana-sqldb-datasource).

Do have a solution so that Grafana supports Postgres ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Grafana only supports Postgres as the data store for Grafana (for storing dashboards, users etc.) and there is no published plugin for using Postgres as a data source.

The MySQL data source plugin has just been added to Grafana and the Postgres plugin is on the Grafana roadmap and should be released later in the year.

If you are wondering why there are so many data sources supported but not Postgres, it is because relational databases are not traditionally what Grafana is used for. The main use case is visualizing time series data (often more data than a relational db can handle). Relational dbs are not built for this use case which is why most people use something like Graphite or InfluxDB. But it is quite common to have some data in a db like Postgres that you would like to show on a dashboard or combine with some data from a time series db. This is why the Grafana team is planning to release a plugin soon.

EDIT: The Postgres data source is now merged to Grafana master and will be released in Grafana 4.6: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/9209

Comment: @ben-jo The Postgres data source has just been merged to master and will be released in Grafana 4.6 (in the next few days). It is available now through the latest nightly build.